# Ajax login portal - how do I automate authentication using a webpage/iframe?

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, cookies, automation

I have been able to accomplish this using Selenium and Python, this is not a viable solution as this must be purely web based(meaning any computer can go to the website and using a known user/password configure the device automatically)

When I try to use '[https://user:password@ipaddress]' it gives me a SSL error:

Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

My hope is that loading the devices web page in an iframe will allow me to use javascript to interact with the devices web interface(login & send form data).

Here is the login.js that is used by the device:

```
function submitLoginInfo() {
    $("#notemsg").html("");
    var authHeader = encodeBase64($("input:radio:checked").attr("value") + ":" + $("input[name='password']").attr("value"));
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "auth.htm?t=" + new Date().toGMTString(),
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authHeader);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            document.cookie = "Authorization=Basic " + authHeader;
            window.location = "/index.htm";
        },
        error: function(request,err,e){
            $("#notemsg").html("<span style='color: red'>Invalid password. Please try again.</span>");
            $("input[name='password']").attr("value", "");
            document.login.password.focus();
        },
        complete: function(request, textStatus) {
        }
    });
}

function resetLoginInfo() {
    $(".loginField").attr("value", "");
    document.login.password.focus();
    $("#notemsg").html("");
}

encodeBase64 = function (input) {
    var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';

    var result = '';
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    do {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        result += chars.charAt(enc1) + chars.charAt(enc2) + chars.charAt(enc3) + chars.charAt(enc4);
    } while (i < input.length);

    return result;
};

function removeCookie() {
    document.cookie = "Authorization=; expires=" + new Date().toGMTString();
}
```

Comment: "*My hope is that loading the devices web page in an iframe will allow me to use javascript to interact*" only if the web page and the page in the iframe are of the same origin.

Comment: The device will be a local IP like [192.168.0.50] I have done this before with other devices but they had less security(I could just user:pass@ip/urlcommand/) and the device would take the user/pass and take the command ect.  I'm stuck on this login.js script I know its something about the header or a cookie but I don't know how to pass that from a webpage.

Comment: What @KevinB said, but if you're not using an iframe and simply logging in, look into providing CORS headers on the device so that browsers don't stop.